# WPF: ListBoxItem with expander cannot expand after adding PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler to parent ListBox

Tags: wpf, events, listbox, event-handling, listboxitem

I have a ListBox, where child items are expanders. I need realize DragDrop event for this. If I write in XAML

```
<ListBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="StartDragDrop">
```

, StartDragDrop method is works good, but child expanders are cannot be expanded. 
If I write

```
<ListBox MouseLeftButtonDown="StartDragDrop">
```

, child expanders are works correct, but StartDragDrop method is not works. 
I think the problem is relates with bubble and tunnel events, but I dont know clear solution. 
I need both, StartDragDrop method and ListBox child expanders Expand method, are work correct. What should I do?

Comment: can you post a bit mode of your XAML? This is not enough to ponder a solution, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is call DoDragDrop mathod at PreviewMouseMove() event, when moving offset is larger than somehow value.

1) Here the list box:

```
<ListBox AllowDrop="True" Drop=" ListBox_Drop" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove">
```

ListBoxItems are Expanders, that cannot expand if we implement DragAndDrop.

2) Now we must add 2 variables (I use VB.NET):

```
Private isDragging As Boolean = False 'flag: is drag operation in process?'
Private dragStartPoint As Point 'coords of dragging start.'
```

3) Remember start point coords by preview mouse click:

```
    Private Sub ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    dragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(Me)
End Sub
```

4) On PreviewMouseMove get moving start point to current moving point offset. If offset is larger than some value, we initiate DragAndDrop operation and set flag isDragging to remember this.

```
Private Sub ListBox_PreviewMouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        Dim diff As Vector = Point.Subtract(dragStartPoint, e.GetPosition(Me))
        If (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance) OrElse (Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance) Then
            If Not isDragging Then 
                isDragging = True 'the flag is active until drop event raises.'
                Dim lstBox As ListBox = TryCast(sender, ListBox) 'get sender ListBox'
                If lstBox IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim data As Object = GetDataFromListBox(lstBox, e.GetPosition(lstBox)) 'get data for drag-and-drop; need to be realized; there are some realizations at Stackoverflow.com presented.'
Dim effects As DragDropEffects = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lstBox, data, DragDropEffects.Move) 'initiate drag-and-drop.'

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

5) Proccessing drop operation:

```
Private Sub ListBox_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        isDragging = False 'reset isDragging flag.'
        Dim lstBox As ListBox = TryCast(sender, ListBox) 'get sender ListBox.'
        If lstBox IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim myObj As MyClass = TryCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(MyClass)), MyClass)
        '...some actions'
        End If
End Sub
```

I've realized this idea and it's works exactly I was need:

- on MouseLeftButtonClick ListBoxItems with Expanders are expands and
  collapses,
- on MouseMove with pressed left button DragAndDrop    operation is
  works, ListBoxItems are able to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You're partially right supposing, that it has to do something with tunneling and bubbling. The tunneling (with preview) event for the outer control is executed before the bubbling (without preview) event. But it doesn't prevent the latter from being executed. This only holds true, when somewhere in the whole event chain `e.Handled` is set to true. See this example:

**XAML:**

```
<Border Background="Red" PreviewMouseMove="OnPreviewMouseMove"> 
  <Border Background="Blue" MouseMove="OnMouseMove" />
</Border>
```

**C#**

```
private void OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Preview outer");
  e.Handled = true;  // this prevents OnMouseMove from being executed
}

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("NoPreview inner");
}
```

If you delete the line "e.Handled = true;", OnMouseMove will be hit. If you don't set this yourself, consider, that a call to base."event-name" might do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it in monday and notify about result.

Comment: After i clicked at my listviewitem, DoDragDrop event rises. And I able to move list items by drag and drop. But expander.expand event is still not rises.

Comment: Ok, I've solved this. The main idea is: 1) by PreviewMouseLeftButton get initial point of moving, 2) after cursor moving offset is larger than MinimumDragDistance an if "isDragging" variable is false, 3) call DoDragDrop method at PreviewMouseMove event, 4) keep  isDragging = true until dropping. I'll post the full code soon.